# How to define a global variable in LLVM and use it in C?

Tags: c, global-variables, llvm

By now, I found only this way: get a pointer to the global variable via a function.

LLVM:

```
@a = global i8 0
define i8* @ggvp_a () {
    ret i8* @a
}
```

C:

```
char* ggvp_a (void);
```

usage:

```
char* gvp_a = ggvp_a ();
*gvp_a = 8;
return *gvp_a;
```

(“ggvp” — “get global variable pointer”)

Is there a more convenient way?

Comment: Have you tried letting clang generate LLVM assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an external declaration like any other - just add

```
extern signed char a;
```

to your `.c` file.

Answer (score 0):

In the file where you reference the global variable, you have to tell LLVM that the variable exists:

### foo.l

```
@foo = global i32 0, align 4
```

### bar.l

```
@foo = external global i32

define i32 @bar() #0 {
  %1 = load i32* @foo, align 4
  ret i32 %1
}
```

The same thing applies when you try to use `foo` from a C source file in which case you have to put an external declaration somewhere:

### baz.c

```
extern int foo;
```

Comment: I ask how to use it in C.

Comment: What do you mean by saying use it in c?

Comment: @HongxuChen He meant »I asked about how to use the global variable from C code«.